# all in one tutorial for mvvm wpf tdd ioc prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control

Aafter almost a year of using wpf in unspeakable ways I understood that "correct" wpf project involves :
`mvvm tdd ioc prism` and perhaps some more stuff.

I wonder if there is a book/tutorial that takes you through creating testdriven mvvm wpf application using prism ?

**I understand each of the techniques seperatly but when trying to combine them to a single project I get a totall mess.**

I know the thread:
[MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)

it didn't provide me something like this,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that "correct" way you're talking about is a gigantic waste of time for small to medium sized projects, except for MVVM (which should be used in every MVVM solution, and doesn't require anything external anyway).

That being said, what you ask for is very specific and as such you're unlikely to find any tutorial covering it.
Instead, you should look for large open source projects and see how they do it, you should find quite a few in CodePlex (the most starred ones on GitHub are surprisingly low quality oO).

I personally use MVVM+PRISM+MEF but no TDD, and the only truly un-separable component is MVVM.

Comment: What is your evidence that it's a "gigantic waste of time?"

Comment: I said "gigantic waste of time **for small to medium sized projects**". I meant it is overengineering.

Comment: My only argument is that it is a blanket statement.  There are some small, and especially some medium-sized, projects that may benefit from one or all of these methodologies.

Comment: I meant to say that using MVVM+PRISM+MEF+TDD on a small to medium sized project was overengineering and wasteful. However I forgot to say to never ditch MVVM, I will add that.

Comment: MVVM is a time saver for most programs that contain more than 3 lines of code.